# Beamer frame with page breaks and pause?

Tags: beamer, pause, allowframebreaks

I have a beamer frame which for some reasons I want to be with the `allowframebreaks` option (to have the frame title counter). I have multiple theorem boxes and a tikZ picture (inside a `figure` environment) on this frame, which spread over 2 pages. Now comes the fun part: I want to add `\pause` between some of the content to reveal it bit by bit, but this seems to mess it up, which I kind of understand, since it's technically still only one frame showing on multiple slides from the frame break *and* the pause at the same time...
Does anyone have a better idea how to do this, or can tell me if this is even possible?
Thanks heaps
F

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Theorems}
    \begin{theorem}
        Suppose $|I|\geq3$ and $\Theta$ is \textbf{rich}:\\
        For any $i,~\theta'_i,~\theta_i$, manipulation $\theta'_i$ is an \textbf{OM} for $\theta_i$ under mechanism $\phi\iff$ for any mechanism $\psi$ \textbf{i-undistinguishable} from $\phi,~\theta'_i$ is a \textbf{profitable} manipulation for $\theta_i$
    \end{theorem}
    %\pause
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \scalebox{.75}{\input{Plot1.tex}} %see my previous question
        %\caption{}
        %\label{fig:f1}
    \end{figure}
    %\pause
    \begin{theorem}
        Any stable-dominating mechanism is \textbf{not obviously manipulable}
    \end{theorem}
    %\pause
    \begin{theorem}
        Any stable mechanism is individually rational, Pareto efficient, and \textbf{not obviously manipulable}
    \end{theorem}
    %\pause
    \begin{theorem}
        The $(K+1)$-price auction is \textbf{not obviously manipulable}
    \end{theorem}
    %\pause
    \begin{theorem}
        Every efficient, individually rational, and weakly budget balanced mechanism is \textbf{obviously manipulable}
    \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure, the contents will all fit onto just 2 slides?

Comment: Yep, it does. It's tight, but it fits! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from the `beamer` user guide:

> You can use the option `allowframebreaks` to cause the `⟨frame text⟩` to
>   be split among several slides, though you cannot use overlays then. (See p. 59)

and:

> The use of this option is evil. In a (good) presentation you prepare
>   each slide carefully and think twice before putting something on a
>   certain slide rather than on some different slide. Using the
>   allowframebreaks option invites the creation of horrible, endless
>   presentations that resemble more a “paper projected on the wall” than
>   a presentation. Nevertheless, the option does have its uses. Most
>   noticeably, it can be convenient for automatically splitting
>   bibliographies or long equations.

As a consequence, I'd manually split the contents into 3 slides as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Theorems I}
    \begin{theorem}
        Suppose $|I|\geq3$ and $\Theta$ is \textbf{rich}:\\
        For any $i,~\theta'_i,~\theta_i$, manipulation $\theta'_i$ is an \textbf{OM} for $\theta_i$ under mechanism $\phi\iff$ for any mechanism $\psi$ \textbf{i-undistinguishable} from $\phi,~\theta'_i$ is a \textbf{profitable} manipulation for $\theta_i$
    \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Theorems II}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \scalebox{.75}{\input{Plot1.tex}} %see my previous question
        %\caption{}
        %\label{fig:f1}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Theorem III}
    \begin{theorem}
        Any stable-dominating mechanism is \textbf{not obviously manipulable}
    \end{theorem}
    \pause
    \begin{theorem}
        Any stable mechanism is individually rational, Pareto efficient, and \textbf{not obviously manipulable}
    \end{theorem}
    \pause
    \begin{theorem}
        The $(K+1)$-price auction is \textbf{not obviously manipulable}
    \end{theorem}
    \pause
    \begin{theorem}
        Every efficient, individually rational, and weakly budget balanced mechanism is \textbf{obviously manipulable}
    \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the user guide info, I must have missed that! The reason I wanted to use `allowframebreaks` _or something similar_ was to have the automatic increment in the frame title. But I guess splitting the frames (as I had it originally) is my only option and I'll have to increment the frame title manually...