# How to make continuation of text in slide using beamer

Tags: beamer, frame

when i am trying to use`\begin{frame}` and`\end{frame}`for a text using beamer, the remaining text after completing a slide is not continued to next slide instead the text is removed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Headline of frame}` See also [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523392](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523392/110998)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50436/allow-theorem-split-in-many-frames-in-beamer